# How to get dialog name or dialog class of MFC dialog?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, mfc, spy++

I have big,old MFC source code. It is very difficult to debug the code. I am using Spy++ to examine one of the dialog. Following is snapshot of Spy++ of the dialog of MFC application.

Is there any way to find name of class of Dialog, or dialog ID?

Secondly, is there any tool in Visual Studio (using 2008) which can map button callback with correct method of source code.

I know second question sounds greedy, but just trying to see if this type of tool exists?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Launch the Debugger.
- Run the application.
- Hit Break All
- Look into the call stack

You should find the code location that calls DoModal. And there you find the appropriate class that is used.